# how to view the sourcesets report in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

im reading [this doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets) which says this:

```
To generate and view this report for your build configuration, proceed as follows:

Click Gradle  on the right side of the IDE window.
Navigate to MyApplication > Tasks > android and double-click sourceSets.
To view the report, click Gradle Console  at the bottom of the IDE window.
```

where is "MyApplication > Tasks > android" I don't see what its referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Gradle Tool Windows. If it is not available as docked tool window on the right side, you can find it at `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`.